# Inferior limit of a sequence ${1, 3, 1, 5, 1, (n+1), ...}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Why in my mathbook they say that this sequence ${1, 3, 1, 5, 1, (n+1), ...}$ does not have neither superior nor inferior limit. I think that it's obvious that it has inferior limit. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Would you mind posting the title and page of the book?

Comment: Of course) It is russian mathbook. So I'll write it in russian: "Основы математического анализа" (Beginnings of analysis), page 63, authors В.А. Ильин (V.A. Ilyin), Э.Г. Позняк (A.G. Poznyak), Publisher "Физматлит", Москва ("Fizmatlit", Moscow).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. The limit inferior is $1$. It is the smallest $L$ such that the original sequence has a subequence converging to $L$.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clearing this for me ;) It is not the first time I see misprints and obvious mistakes in this book. Going to prepare a list of this staff and send it to the publisher.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the book is wrong, the lim inf is clearly $1$.

By definition:

$$\liminf_{n\to\infty}x_n := \lim_{n\to\infty}\Big(\inf_{m\geq n}x_m\Big)$$

or

$$\liminf_{n\to\infty}x_n := \sup_{n\geq 0}\,\inf_{m\geq n}x_m=\sup\{\,\inf\{\,x_m:m\geq n\,\}:n\geq 0\,\}.$$

In your case $\inf_{m\geq n}x_m = 1$ for any $n>0$.